# Bounded square sum algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The problem goes as follows:

```
You are given two arrays of integers a and b, and two integers lower and upper. 
Your task is to find the number of pairs (i, j) such that lower ≤ a[i] * a[i] + b[j] * b[j] ≤ upper.

Example:

For a = [3, -1, 9], b = [100, 5, -2], lower = 7, and upper = 99, the output should be boundedSquareSum(a, b, lower, upper) = 4.
There are only four pairs that satisfy the requirement:
If i = 0 and j = 1, then a[0] = 3, b[1] = 5, and 7 ≤ 3 * 3 + 5 * 5 = 9 + 25 = 36 ≤ 99.
If i = 0 and j = 2, then a[0] = 3, b[2] = -2, and 7 ≤ 3 * 3 + (-2) * (-2) = 9 + 4 = 13 ≤ 99.
If i = 1 and j = 1, then a[1] = -1, b[1] = 5, and 7 ≤ (-1) * (-1) + 5 * 5 = 1 + 25 = 26 ≤ 99.
If i = 2 and j = 2, then a[2] = 9, b[2] = -2, and 7 ≤ 9 * 9 + (-2) * (-2) = 81 + 4 = 85 ≤ 99.
For a = [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3], b = [10], lower = 0, and upper = 100, the output should be boundedSquareSum(a, b, lower, upper) = 0.
Since the array b contains only one element 10 and the array a does not contain 0, it is not possible to satisfy 0 ≤ a[i] * a[i] + 10 * 10 ≤ 100.
```

Now, I know there is a brute force way to solve this, but what would be the optimal solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort the smaller array using the absolute value of the elements, then for each element in the unsorted array, binary search the interval on the sorted one.

Comment: It's OK to sort just one of them, and iterate over an unsorted one.

Comment: @גלעדברקן can you explain the part "binary search the interval on the sorted one". What do you mean by 'search the interval'?

Comment: @Marko take just the lower bound of the interval, `lb`, for example. Since `a^2 + b^2` is monotonically increasing for a fixed `a` (the element from the unsorted array in our current iteration) as we move along the sorted array, we can use the rules of binary search: if `a^2 + b^2` is greater than `lb`, there's no point in looking to the right of `b` since the sum will grow, so we look in the part left of `b`, similarly for when `a^2 + b^2` is smaller than `lb` there's no point in looking farther left.

Comment: @Marko I mean binary search each bound of the interval separately. Then calculate how many numbers are in the interval using the formula right_index - left_index + 1.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So the complexity would be n * log n?

Comment: You could use a two-pointer technique instead of repeated binary search, making the second phase O(n). The whole algorithm would still be O(n log n) due to sorting, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can `break` loop when calculation goes higher than `upper` limit.
I will reduce execution time.

```
function boundedSquareSum(a, b, lower, upper) {
    let result = 0; 
    a = a.sort((i,j) => Math.abs(i) - Math.abs(j));
    b = b.sort((i,j) => Math.abs(i) - Math.abs(j))
    
    
 
    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        let aValue = a[i] ** 2;
        
        if(aValue > upper) {
            break; // Don't need to check further
        }
        
        for(let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            let bValue = b[j] ** 2;
            let total = aValue + bValue;
            
            if(total > upper) {
                break; // Don't need to check further
            }
            
            if((total >= lower && total <= upper) ) {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    return result;
}
```